I keep getting an ImportError:no module named 'gfx_pack' , when coding a game on the rasperrby pi pico H
I am new to coding so not sure what to do, I am using the Pico GFX pack by pimororni. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!!
I tried other example codes from the pimoroni website and the gfx pack class mentioned on the site.

This tutorial say that you need to install a custom firmware. Did you do that.
The import error means that the import gfx_pack command can't find the gfx_pack module, which (in the normal case) you'd install via pip or some other python package management software. In this case, however, I think it is a bit different (i.e. you need special firmware, which hopefully should have everything set up so import gfx_pack works)

You need a the micro python from pimoroni to work with the GFX PACK
